# Замена подстроки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка. Мне нужно по регулярному выражению обернуть все совпадения в тег `span`. Делаю так:

```php
$str = 'Строка для замена';
$str = preg_replace("/(без|для|на|)/", "<span>${n}</span>", $str);
echo $str;
```

Получаю ошибку. Пишет, что есть неизвестная переменная `n` во второй строке. Как поправить, чтобы можно было находить любое количество совпадений в строке и обрамлять их тегом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${n} -> $1

```
$str = preg_replace("/(без|для|на)/", "<span>$1</span>", $str);
```

Comment: Сработало. Спасибо!

Comment: Зачем здесь подмаска вообще? `preg_replace("/без|для|на/u", '<span>$0</span>', $str);`

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы целое совпадение обернуть каким-нибудь тегом, можно воспользоваться **обратной ссылкой на целое совпадение** в шаблоне замены.

В PHP это `$0`:

```
$str = preg_replace("/без|для|на/u", '<span>$0</span>', $str);
```

Всё, что найдёт регулярное выражение, и будет подставлено в результат между `<span>` и `</span>`.

`$0` можно также использовать в [java](/questions/tagged/java) (`x.replaceAll("\\d+", "<span>$0</span>")`), Notepad++, [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) (`x.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\d+", with: "<span>$0</span>", options: [.regularExpression]`) и [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (`std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("\\d+"), "<span>$0</span>");` / `std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("\\d+"), "<span>$&</span>")`).

В Notepad++ и C++ `std::regex` можно использовать как `$&`, так и `$0`.

**В других языках**

**`$&`**:
 - [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23): `Regex.Replace(x, @"\d+", "<span>$&</span>")`
 - [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript): `x.replace(/\d+/g, '<span>$&</span>')` 
 - [perl](/questions/tagged/perl): `$ч =~ s/\d+/<span>$&</span>/g`
**`\0`**:
 - [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby): `x.gsub(/\d+/, '<span>\0</span>')`
 - [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl): `regsub -all {\d+} $x {<span>\0</span>} result`
 - [r](/questions/tagged/r) (*stringr*): , `str_replace(x, "\\d+", "<span>\\0</span>")`
**`\g<0>`**:
 - [python](/questions/tagged/python): `re.sub(r"\d+", r"<span>\g<0></span>", x)`
**`%0`**:
 - [lua](/questions/tagged/lua): `string.gsub(x, "%d+", "<span>%0</span>")`
**`&`**:
 - [sed](/questions/tagged/sed): `sed 's,[0-9][0-9]*,<span>&</span>,g' file`
**Отсутствует (т.е. придётся заключить всё выражение в захватывающую подмаску и использовать `\1` в шаблоне замены)** в 
 - [r](/questions/tagged/r) (в базовых функциях R, в которых используется библиотека TRE / PCRE)

Comment: Сколько всего... Спасибо!